# Use Solr to index/search txt file content

Tags: apache, solr

I'm making a study to compare different search platforms' performance over Twitter's tweets. For my purpose I have collected a set of tweets (around 50,000) and saved them in a single text (`.txt`) file in a format similar to the following:

```
Tweet ID    User    Tweet Content   Tweet Time-stamp
```

The data would look like this:

```
31261817690923008   username1   tweet 1 content goes here   1482180069
31132193287839744   username2   tweet 2 content goes here   1274400000
```

Now, using Solr 6.3.0, is it possible to index each line of content separately? Instead, should I use XML or JSON? or do I have to store each line (tweet) in a different file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CSV Update Handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVFormattedIndexUpdates), which will result in a single document for each row.

To adjust the parsing to the structure you've used, you can use `separator` (TAB? %09) to provide the separator used between fields / columns, `encapsulator` to set the value used to encapsulate a single field value (it doesn't seem you've used any) and `fieldnames` to provide a proper field name for each column, unless they're in the first row - in that case set `header` to true (and don't provide fieldnames).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming two things:

#1 You do not want to do an awful lot of coding for the data entry.

#2 Your text file is TAB or comma separated. 
If so, you can easily turn it into an XML that can be added via the Admin interface.

A few things to keep in mind:

Enclose your data in `<add> ... </add>` blocks of a reasonable size. Ideally not 50K. Experiment a little.

Enclose each entry - line in your case in `<doc> ... <doc>`

Each column needs to have its own field as in

```
<field name="id"> ... </field>
<field name="username"> ... </field>
...
```

All need unique IDs.
For practical purposes, if you can open the textfile in a spreadsheet, add the tag columns in between your data and then concatenate the lines, it is relatively easy even if a little labour intensive for 50K.
A doc set of two would look something like:

```
<add>       
<doc>       
<field name="id">   ... </field>
<field name="user"> ... </field>
<field name="content">  ... </field>
<field name="time_stamp">   ... </field>
</doc>      

<doc>       
<field name="id">   ... </field>
<field name="user"> ... </field>
<field name="content">  ... </field>
<field name="time_stamp">   ... </field>
</doc>      
</add>
```